# Where would it be quicker to sort a collection - client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, client-side, server-side

I have a question concerning client side vs. server side processing.

I have a rather big collection of objects (lets say a collection of "user" objects which consists of everyday fields - `name`, `last name`, `age`, `isAdmin` etc...)

Now, I want to separate this big collection into two small collections where the predicate is a boolean field - `isAdmin` - which tells us if the user is an admin or not.

After the separation I will need to send both final collections to the server side for some more complex processing.

I was wondering where it will be more efficient to do the sorting and spliting in the client side (using Javascript or jQuery perhaps? would it do the trick?) or just send the big collection to the server and let it handle everything (both splitting using LINQ and further processing).

And generally, in which cases is it better to use client side over server side? and why?

Answer (score 4):

As always, performance questions are hard to answer in general, so it depends on:

- the size of your dataset (does "rather big collection" mean 100's or 1000000's ?)
- the client-side and server-side hardware
- the network latency and transmission speed ...

You'd really have to do some testing to figure this one out.  Even then, because every user could be on a different computer, the answer might be different for me on my 2001-vintage hardware compared to somebody with a 2011 quad-core with 16GB of memory and the most efficient javascript interpreter.

Comment: in my case... big collection would be 10's of results... both client and server are strong machines... network might have lags. How does it change the answer?

Comment: For that small a number, then my guess is that you'd be much better off doing it client side.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no simple answer to this, as there are a lot of variables at play such as:

- Computing power
- Computing workload
- Sorting algorithm implementations in various languages (*please* remember that jQuery is **not** a language)

... and probably a bunch of other things.

It used to be the case that we could say that the server was always faster than the client, but that isn't necessarily true anymore because of the high availability of powerful computing and the commoditization of application hosting.

But besides speed, there are other things to consider, such as security. If your User object contains sensitive information, do you really want to trust a client's computer with that data?

Comment: "do you really want to trust a client's computer with that data?". If i could upvote for this statement more than one time.